# Removing the need for capital letter in Ruby create for a DSL

Tags: ruby, dsl

I wrote a simple DSL that works with a call like:

```
create Pizza do 
    spread cheese
    spread sauce
    toppings shoes, jalapeno, apples
    bake
end
```

I would like to remove the uppercase P to make this call a little cleaner but I'm having trouble finding a way to make that possible.

Here is my code for PizzaBuilder.rb

```
class PizzaIngredients #factory


    def initialize
        @@order = {}
    end

    def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
        name.to_s
    end


    def spread (spread)
        @@order[:spreads] ||= []
        @@order[:spreads]  << spread
    end

    def bake
        @@order
    end

    def create (pizza)
        "making the #{pizza}"
    end

    def toppings (*toppingList)
        @@order[:toppings] ||= []
        @@order[:toppings]  += toppingList
    end
end

module Pizza #smokestack
    @order = []
    def self.order
        @order
    end

    def self.create(&block)
        pizza = PizzaIngredients.new
        pizza.instance_eval(&block)
    end
end

def create (param, &block)
    Pizza.create(&block)
end
```

Comment: Are `cheese`, `jalapeno` defined? Didn't you mean to use symbols there? If they're defined, you can define `pizza` the same way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I can't because "spread" and "toppings" is defined inside Pizza. I need to define the create first.  I came across an answer, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@suavocado - The capital letter is part of the conventions used by Ruby programmers all over the world...

Constants start with capital letters. variables use small letters... It's part of how we code and how we design....

These conventions are hard coded into the Ruby interperter.

Try the following code and see for your self:

```
class Pizza
   def self.test
     "hello!"
   end
end

Object.const_set 'Pita', Pizza # => okay

Object.const_set 'pizza', Pizza # => error
```

As some of the comments mentioned, you could use a symbol instead of a constant for your DSL, i.e.

```
create :pizza do
    # ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.  I'm still very inexperienced and my fix seemed like a simple solution to achieve my goal. Full disclosure, this is also a part of an assignment and I was asked to make the DSL as close to natural english as possible.

Comment: @suavocado , I guess that as assignments go, it's kinda cool that you implemented a hack to make it feel as if `pizza` is a reserved Ruby keyword such as `while` or `if`... having said that, I wonder if you considered someone using your DSL to create a pizza, going `pizza = create pizza do #...` ... this would make it a single use DSL... Real life design teaches us that people use our code in many different (often frightening) ways... conventions are your friends ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using this in the global scope

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    name.to_s == "pizza"? name.to_s : super
end
```

Comment: If you post a better fix I'd be happy to give you credit.  I'm pretty new to Ruby and DSL's.

Comment: Please notice, as mentioned by others: ["If you’re going to use method_missing, be sure to implement respond_to? in kind."](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods/) ... and in general, this feature should be avoided when possible.